# Scanf a char in C with an example

Tags: c, char, variable-assignment, arrays

I was doing a tutorial at [Cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

There was this example:

```
/* scanf example */
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char str [80];
  int i;

  printf ("Enter your family name: ");
  scanf ("%79s",str);  
  printf ("Enter your age: ");
  scanf ("%d",&i);
  printf ("Mr. %s , %d years old.\n",str,i);
  printf ("Enter a hexadecimal number: ");
  scanf ("%x",&i);
  printf ("You have entered %#x (%d).\n",i,i);

  return 0;
}
```

I tried it on my Macbook and when I do "make example" I get this error;

```
example.c: In function ‘main’:
example.c:25: warning: format ‘%79s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[80]’
```

When I do "valgrind ./example" I get this message;

```
==1326== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1326== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1326== Using Valgrind-3.6.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1326== Command: ./example
==1326== 
--1326-- ./example:
--1326-- dSYM directory is missing; consider using --dsymutil=yes
Enter your family name: Park
Enter your age: 20
Mr. Park, 20 years old.
==1326== 
==1326== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1326==     in use at exit: 8,280 bytes in 3 blocks
==1326==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 0 frees, 8,280 bytes allocated
==1326== 
==1326== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1326==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1326==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1326==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1326==    still reachable: 8,280 bytes in 3 blocks
==1326==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1326== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==1326== 
==1326== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1326== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**Question 1.**
The "make example" gives an error but the program does what it should do. 
Then what is the error here?

**Question 2**
I did little research and I learned that you can't assign a char in C since a char is not mutable. That is what a char differs from int or float or double. If so, how could I have assigned str here?

**Question 3**
What is the Char array? I read several articles but I don't get how it works here!!!

```
char str [80];
```

means str can take up to 80 bytes, right?
Then what is

```
scanf ("%79s",str);
```

?

Thank you so much for your help guys and happy 2014! :)

Comment: ad 1) it is a warning, not an error. I think the message is pretty explicit about what it is warning about, i.e. the type of `str` is a character array, while a pointer was expected.

Comment: Declare `i` as `unsigned int i;`

Comment: Given the warning, are you sure you didn't have `&str` in the `scanf` call before? You see, `&str` is of type `char (*)[80]`, but `str` is totally right and should not give you a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

```
example.c:25: warning: format ‘%79s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[80]’
```

only makes sense if you had written something like

```
scanf ("%79s", &str); // wrong
```

instead of

```
scanf ("%79s",str);  // right
```

Is the code you posted what you're actually compiling?

As to your specific questions:

> Question 1. The "make example" gives an error but the program does what it should do. Then what is the error here?

First, a little background: except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

When you write

```
scanf("%79s", str);
```

the expression `str` has type "80-element array of `char`"; since `str` is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it is converted to an expression of type "pointer to `char`", or `char *`, and its value is the address of the first element in the array.

If you had written

```
scanf("%79s", &str);
```

the expression `str` is the operand of the unary `&` operator, so the conversion doesn't happen; instead, the type of the expression `&str` is "pointer to *80-element array of* `char`", or `char (*)[80]` (look familiar?) and the value of the expression is the address of the array.

Now, it just so happens that the address of an array and the address of the first element of an array are the same; the expressions `str` and `&str` will yield the same *value*, but the types of the two expressions are different.

So, assuming you had written `scanf("%79s, &str)`, the code will still "work" (the value of `&str` is the same as `str`), but since the type isn't want `scanf` expects for the `%s` conversion specifier, the compiler emits a warning.

> Question 2 I did little research and I learned that you can't assign a char in C since a char is not mutable. That is what a char differs from int or float or double. If so, how could I have assigned str here?

Either you've misunderstood, or you're reading a *very* bad reference.  Strings in C are *not* immutable; attempting to modify the contents of a string *literal* invokes undefined behavior (some platforms will throw an exception, some won't), but that's not the same as saying they are immutable in the same way Java strings are immutable.

Strings in C are stored as arrays of `char`.  You can update string contents by using the `strcpy` library function or by modifying the array elements directly.  For example:

```
char str[80];
...
strcpy( str, "a string" );
```

copies the contents of the string literal `"a string"` to `str`.  You can certainly update this string, such as

```
str[0] = 'A'; // str now contains "A string"
```

or append another string to it:

```
strcat( str, " with more stuff" ); // str now contains "A string with more stuff"
```

String *literals* like `"a string"` are stored as arrays of `char` such that their storage is allocated when the program starts and held until the program exits, and they are visible over the entire program.  Trying to modify the contents of a string literal invokes undefined behavior; it may work, it may not, the compiler may throw an error, you may get an error at runtime.  So you don't want to do something like

```
char *p = "This is a test";
strcpy( p, "This is another test" );
```

> Question 3 What is the Char array? I read several articles but I don't get how it works here!!!
>
> ```
> char str [80];
> ```
>
> means str can take up to 80 bytes, right?

It takes up 80 `char`s; it's *usually* true that a `char` maps to a native 8-bit byte, but there are exceptions (mostly either very old architectures or oddball embedded systems).

> Then what is
>
> ```
> scanf ("%79s",str);
> ```
>
> ?

In that call, all `scanf` receives is a pointer to the first element of the target buffer; it has no idea how big the target buffer actually is.  If you wrote

```
scanf("%s", str);
```

and the user typed in a string that was more than 80 characters long, `scanf` would happily store those extra characters to the memory immediately following the end of `str`, potentially clobbering something important and leading to a crash (or worse, a malware exploit).  The `%79s` directs `scanf` to only read up to 79 characters from the input stream.  Why 79 instead of 80?  You need to leave one element available for the 0 terminator (in C, a *string* is a sequence of characters terminated by a 0-valued byte).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! :D The last part of your answer was exactly what I needed! I'm a newbie in C and C is just so not intuitive compare to Python. Thank you again! P.S.-I mistyped &str, it should have been just str.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
scanf ("%79s", str);
```

means "read a string (`s`) but don't use more than 79 characters of space starting from the pointer I've given you", sort of. It's a way to prevent buffer overflow when reading strings. It's using `79` rather than `80` to leave room for the string terminator.

[The documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) says:

> String input conversions store a terminating null byte (`'\0'`) to mark the end of the input; the maximum field width does not include this terminator.

Comment: and that's why using `scanf()` is dangerous and should be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

> I was doing a tutorial at Cplusplus

**Please don't.** That site is full of bad, incorrect and/or misleading examples. Do yourself a favor and choose another site.

> I tried it on my Macbook and when I do "make example" I get this error;

Probably you misspelled the source code and you wrote `&str` instead of `str` (I think it's a bad habit: throwing in the address-of operator without thinking when you encounter `scanf()`). That results in a pointer-to-array whereas the conversion specifier expects a pointer-to-char.

> The "make example" gives an error but the program does what it should do. Then what is the error here?

The program does **not** do what it should. Instead, it invokes **undefined behavior,** and it **pretends** to work correctly.

> I did little research and I learned that you can't assign a char in C since a char is not mutable

Wrong.

> What is the Char array?

The char array in your example is `str`. It's just that: an array of 80 chars. Unfortunately, arrays have some bizarre properties in C, such as implicitly decaying into pointers when passed to a function. That is the reason `scanf()` wants you to pass a pointer and not an array argument: when you write

```
scanf("format string", str);
```

then what is actually passed is a pointer to the first element in `str` (a. k. a. `&str[0]`).

---

Also, if you accept one more piece of good advice: **don't use `scanf()`.** It's dangerous, its usage is counter-intuitive, and it doesn't do any good in general. For accepting user input, consider using `fgets()` instead.

Comment: also add suggestions about initialization. will be really helpful.

Comment: @Koushik Sorry? What kind of initialization do you mean?

Comment: ...and before you ask why `cplusplus.com` is "bad" [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11972076/1870232)

Comment: @H2CO3 the variables that he has used. here its (not)ok but in general its always a good idea is'nt it?.

Comment: @Koushik No, not necessarily. It all depends on the context. Sometimes it's good, sometimes it's superfluous.

Comment: @H2CO3 if the read would have failed? usually i do check for scanf's return code but then if i don't do that, i still have an uninitialized variable on error.. Yes it is very defensive programming:-)

Comment: @Koushik That's why you don't *usually* check the return value, but rather *always.* Although I see where you're coming from (but sometimes it can even hide the error... especially if you are doing a debug build, where uninitialized variables are initialized by some compilers to a special value that crashes on purpose at runtime... that can be very helpful.)

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks for your answer! I did a research on the Internet based on your advice(which took me more than 5 hours....) and I think I resolved parts of my curiosity. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and I did misspelled str. I mistyped as &str which becomes a pointer.

Comment: @YOUNG Yup, that's what I (we) suspected.